# Animate two paths in one function with Snap Svg

Tags: animation, svg, snap.svg

i need some help with this, im trying to animate two paths in only one function with Snap svg.

Im trying this but it is not working, just animate the first one.

```
    svg = document.getElementById('Capa_1_plato');
s = Snap(svg);
var path = Snap.select('#ondas');
var path2 = Snap.select('#ondasAceite');
animatePath();
function animatePath(){
  path.animate({ d: "M520.5 132.6c4.4 1.5 11.3 3.3 19.9 3.1 7.7-.1 11.3-3.5 19.4-3.6 6.6-.1 12 1.6 15.4 3"}, 2000, mina.linear, resetPath);
  path2.animate({ d: "M219.6 153.2c.5-.2 1.5-.6 2.3-.6 1.4 0 2 .2 2.8.6.9.4 2 .9 4 .8 2 0 3.1-.5 4-1 .8-.3 1.4-.6 2.8-.6s2 .2 2.8.6c.9.4 2 .9 4 .8s3.1-.5 4-1c.8-.3 1.4-.6 2.8-.6.9 0 1.4.1 1.9.3.1 0 .7.2.8 0 1.1-2 .5-2.8.5-2.8-.8-.3-1.7-.5-3-.5-2 0-3.1.5-4 1-.8.3-1.4.6-2.8.6s-2-.2-2.8-.6c-.9-.4-2-.9-4-.8-2 0-3.1.5-4 1-.8.3-1.4.6-2.8.6s-2-.2-2.8-.6c-.9-.4-2-.9-4-.8-1.3 0-2.5.4-3.2.7-.8 1.6.7 2.9.7 2.9z"}, 2000, mina.linear, resetPath);
}
function resetPath(){
    path.animate({ d: "M519.5 135.3c4.4-1.5 11.3-3.3 19.9-3.1 7.7.1 11.3 3.5 19.4 3.6 6.6.1 12-1.6 15.4-3" }, 2000, mina.linear, animatePath);
  path2.animate({ d: "M219.6 150.4c.5.2 1.5.6 2.3.6 1.4 0 2-.2 2.8-.6.9-.4 2-.9 4-.9s3.1.5 4 .9c.8.3 1.4.6 2.8.6s2-.2 2.8-.6c.9-.4 2-.9 4-.9s3.1.5 4 .9c.8.3 1.4.6 2.8.6.9 0 1.4-.1 1.9-.3.1 0 .7-.2.8 0 1.2 2 .5 2.8.5 2.8-.8.3-1.7.5-3 .5-2 0-3.1-.5-4-.9-.8-.3-1.4-.6-2.8-.6s-2 .2-2.8.6c-.9.4-2 .9-4 .9s-3.1-.5-4-.9c-.8-.3-1.4-.6-2.8-.6s-2 .2-2.8.6c-.9.4-2 .9-4 .9-1.3 0-2.5-.4-3.2-.7-.8-1.7.7-2.9.7-2.9z"}, 2000, mina.linear, resetPath);
}
```

And the HTML is:

```
<svg id="Capa_1_plato" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 780 1374">
<path id="ondas" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="4" d="M519.5 135.3c4.4-1.5 11.3-3.3 19.9-3.1 7.7.1 11.3 3.5 19.4 3.6 6.6.1 12-1.6 15.4-3"/>
<path id="#ondasAceite" class="st2" d="M219.6 150.4c.5.2 1.5.6 2.3.6 1.4 0 2-.2 2.8-.6.9-.4 2-.9 4-.9s3.1.5 4 .9c.8.3 1.4.6 2.8.6s2-.2 2.8-.6c.9-.4 2-.9 4-.9s3.1.5 4 .9c.8.3 1.4.6 2.8.6.9 0 1.4-.1 1.9-.3.1 0 .7-.2.8 0 1.2 2 .5 2.8.5 2.8-.8.3-1.7.5-3 .5-2 0-3.1-.5-4-.9-.8-.3-1.4-.6-2.8-.6s-2 .2-2.8.6c-.9.4-2 .9-4 .9s-3.1-.5-4-.9c-.8-.3-1.4-.6-2.8-.6s-2 .2-2.8.6c-.9.4-2 .9-4 .9-1.3 0-2.5-.4-3.2-.7-.8-1.7.7-2.9.7-2.9z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo I think in your id. You have

```
<path id="#ondasAceite" ...
```

Change that to

```
<path id="ondasAceite" ...
```